# Is this a valid SQL query?

Tags: sql

This is just an example, I'm doing something similar that is going to grab thousands of records.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT * FROM zoodb) As TblA 
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT animal_ID, Max(checkup_year) AS latest_checkup FROM TblA GROUP BY animal_ID) as TblB 
ON (TblA.animal_ID = TblB.animal_ID) AND (TblA.checkup_year = TblB.latest_checkup)
```

Basically in this, I want to grab the records only for the latest checkup year

Comment: Best way to know if it's valid - run it!

Comment: You don't need all that, check my answer :)

Comment: On which **database** ?? SQL is just the structured query language - hardly really well defined and hardly a strict standard. Whether this runs is probably dependent on which RDBMS you run it on ....

Comment: @JNK without running it we can see that's invalid :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your query is not valid.**

---

But you can do it this way:

```
SELECT * FROM zoodb z
INNER JOIN (SELECT animal_ID, Max(checkup_year) AS latest_checkup
            FROM zoodb
            GROUP BY animal_ID) aux ON aux.animal_ID = z.animal_ID AND aux.latest_checkup = z.checkup_year
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT * FROM zoodb) As TblA 
....
```

There is no need for this sub query. The `FROM` in the outer query can handle it!

```
SELECT * 
FROM zoodb AS TblA
...
```

The rest looks fine!

Edit:

As aF pointed out you cannot reference TblA from the inner join subquery (See aF's answer).

Comment: the select with the group by uses TblA, he can't do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

aF.'s answer is correct, but I thought I'd propose a solution that expresses your intention a little more clearly:

```
select *
from zoodb as TblA
where latest_checkup = (
    select max(latest_checkup)
    from zoodb
    where animal_id = TblA.animal_id);
```

The lack of the [inner join (subselect)] also means that it won't get too messy if you need to add additional constraints in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Also the query optimizer prefers inner joins to nested select statements, so you'll get a more optional execution plan